# Driver issues with porting code to new computer (CL_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE...Build Program driver returned (517))

Tags: c, macos, opencl, amd-gpu

I have a piece of code that I'm able to run on my iMac, and I'm trying to get it to run on a Mac Pro that I'm using for work.  However, after doing a `git clone` to put the code on my Mac Pro, I'm running into an issue where I can't run the code via the GPU, and I'm pretty stumped.

- Computer #1 (code works): Late 2013 iMac, macOS Mojave (10.14.6), GPU is an NVIDIA GeForce GT 755M 1 GB
- Computer #2 (code does not work): Late 2013 Mac Pro, OS X Yosemite (10.10.3), GPU is an AMD FirePro D500 3072 MB

I do not believe that the difference in OS is the issue; I ran El Capitan on my iMac until about a week ago, and the code ran fine (no changes to the program have been made since then).

When I run the program on the Mac Pro, I get the following error:

```
14:42:45 : RS : [CL_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE] : OpenCL Error : Error: Build Program driver returned (517) (via pfn_notify)

14:42:45 : RS : OpenCL Warning : clBuildProgram failed: could not build program for 0x1021c00 (AMD Radeon HD - FirePro D500 Compute Engine) (err:-2) (via pfn_notify)

14:42:45 : RS : [CL_BUILD_ERROR] : OpenCL Build Error : Compiler build log:

Error returned by cvms_element_build_from_source
(via pfn_notify)

14:42:45 : RS: ERROR: CL Compilation failed:
Error returned by cvms_element_build_from_source
```

I can run the code on the Mac Pro on the CPU, but I cannot get the code to run on the GPU. Is there some sort of driver that I'm missing, or is there something else in the code that I need to change?

Comment: There's not a lot to go on here with no source code. Is "Compiler build log:" the entirety of the `CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG` output? If so, you'll probably need to apply a divide and conquer approach to narrowing down the issue: comment out areas of kernel code to see if that makes it build, to find the area that causes the failure. macOS's OpenCL compiler is notoriously unhelpful, unfortunately.

Comment: Assuming your code doesn't have a bug as such, a possible hardware-dependent limitation is running out of private "memory" (i.e. register file). This should normally spill to local or global memory, but maybe not. So if you're using a lot of private memory in your kernel, see if you can reduce it down and whether that solves the problem.